# Add row count to a table that dynamically changes if the order of rows change - WEBI 4.0

Tags: sorting, business-objects

I have added a table in the webi designer. This is made up of 2 columns, "category" and "measure" and there are 3 rows of data. I wanted to add a column that will hold the row count, so I added a third column titled, row count, and added the formula

```
=(RowIndex())
```

This appeared to work as it now populated with 1,2,3 in that order. But if I sort the table by measure ascending, this sort works but my row count is now 2,3,1  in that order. I think this is to do with the formula =(RowIndex()) pulls back the "row count" from the intial sql order and then does not update.

Is there a way to update this so row count is dynamic and recalculates as different sorts are added. So it always stays in order i.e 1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `RowIndex()` represents the row number from the SQL result set (the "microcube").  You want to use `RunningCount()` instead.

`RunningCount()` requires a dimension or measure object as a parameter, as it counts non-null values.  But you can pass a static value to count all rows: `=RunningCount(1)`

Comment: That worked great and thank for the explanation. Cheers